# ActiveMq : Consumer has been increase automatically

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I required only one consumer but it is increasing the consumers after some time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this given below :

```
activemq:queue:incomingQueue?concurrentConsumers=1
```

Comment: You mean in Consumer side i have to write like this:                Session session=connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
   Queue queue=session.createQueue("SendSynchronousMsgQueue?concurrentConsumers=1");